# Is there such a data-structure that combines queue and hashmap?

Tags: data-structures

Is there such a data structure that combines a `Queue` and a `Hashmap`?

In addition to the FIFO (`enqueue`/`dequeue`) behaviour where a queue normally has, I want

- when enqueuing, always enqueue with a `key`,
- when peeking without the key, returns the head of the queue
- when peeking with the key, returns the first element enqueued with this key
- when dequeuing without the key, remove the first element ever enqueued
- when dequeuing with the key, remove all elements having the key

I wonder if such data structure already exist in the wild?

Comment: A queue with a key is a priority queue. But the keys must be distinct and orderable.

Comment: @miparnisari Thanks for pointing out. Though the key being orderable/sortable is not the property I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

No there is not. But you can combine both to achieve the behavior you want (though you will have to make tradeoffs along the way).

To do so, you will store:

- A HashMap where the values are references to items in the queue: `HashMap<Key, ReferenceToFIFOElement>` or `HashMap<Key, Set<ReferenceToFIFOElement>>`.
- An actual FIFO queue: `FIFO<Item>`

When you enqueue, you first add your element at the top of the queue. Then you update the hashmap with a reference to this newly created element if the key was not registered yet (or add the said reference to the reference bucket mapped to the given key in the set case).

Peeking will be easy: just retrieve the key and access the referenced item (or the first referenced item in the set case, or the top if no key were provided).

Dequeuing is where the real tradeoff will take place:

- If you only store a reference to the first item inserted with a given key in the hashmap, then you will have to iterate over all the queue, starting from the said item. **This means an overall higher time complexity.**
- If you store all the references to items with a given key in the hashmap (using a set), then you will just have to iterate over that set and remove the referenced elements from the queue. **This increases the space complexity of the data structure**.

However, in reality it can be more complicated depending on the data structure you choose to place under the hood of the FIFO:

- Array list: cache friendly, random access... But can require reallocation as you insert/delete elements. This invalidates references -> store indices instead of actual references.
- Linked list: not cache friendly but insertion and deletion are guaranteed to be O(1).